# Open links in loop - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have written a script that opens always, more or less, the same link but with another ID. Which is the variable in the loop. My script looks actually like this and I would only like to know how I can open this link with the variable as an ID:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="openLinks();">Click </button>

<script>
    function openLinks() {
        var i;

        for (i = 150; i < 156; i++) {
            window.open('http://www.someurl.at/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpsl_store_editor&action=edit_store&store_id="i"'); //doesn't work, should print 150, 151...
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try this in the console: `"store_id="+3`

Comment: Pop up blocker will block that....

Comment: That doesn't work. And no, the PopUp Blocker is no problem, I am using it for personal use and I deactivated the blocker for this html site

Comment: @epascarello Will a popup blocker will block it due to `actions per time ` or due to  `many actions` or due to `window.open which is not via user click` ( and if so  , what about 2...n clicks)?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not adding the variable as a string to your url.

Try something like this:

```
 window.open("http://www.ortner.elmima.at/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpsl_store_editor&action=edit_store&store_id=" + String(i));
```

Comment: That's not necessary at all.

Comment: No problem. :-) @SebastianNette How so?

Comment: @aznbanana9 Because you can concat strings and integers just fine. `"text" + i` is already a string. `String(i)` and `""+i` pretty much do the same.

Comment: Agreed, though for the sake of good practice, would you say it is better to explicitly call the global constructor `String`?

Answer (score 0):

If you put double quotes inside a single quote JS engine will understand it as a regular character not a variable. " and ' is string literals, however, you should use only one of them.

You should write something like this

```
var link = "someurl" + i;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `string`/`number` concatenation problem :

Change :

```
 window.open('http://www.someurl.at/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpsl_store_editor&action=edit_store&store_id="i"');
```

To

```
 window.open('http://www.someurl.at/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpsl_store_editor&action=edit_store&store_id='+i);
```

The `i` within `store_id="i"'` is not dynamically evaluated.You have to "take out" the `i` as a string to a dynamic loop variable which concats to the string.

Answer (score 0):

How would you build any normal string?

```
var x = "asdfg" + i;
```

so what you are doing is no different.

```
....tor&action=edit_store&store_id=' + i)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
window.open('http://www.someurl.at/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpsl_store_editor&action=edit_store&store_id="' + i + '"');
```

so that `i` does not render as part of a string, but rather to mean the variable.